# Moving floats to end with latexpand

Tags: floats, endfloat

Is it possible, with latexpand (or if not, with an another approach) to move code for floats (e.g. tables) to the end of a document?  I have a paper with tables/figures located in situ but many journals want them at the end.  This is easily accomplished with endfloat.  However, I also want to 'flatten' my complex .tex document (with tables produced elsewhere and added via \input) to produce a single document.  This can be done with latexpand, but this leaves the tables etc where they are found in the document.  I want to move the actual code within the document.  (Broader context: this is relevant e.g. when submitting to the journal, where you often need a single .tex file).

MWE: call this file text.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{endfloat}
\begin{document}
    Some text.  
    \begin{table}[h]
        In real life there is a table here.
    \end{table}
    Some more text.
%I would like \begin{table}...\end{table} to appear here.
\end{document}
```

Then flatten this by running `perl latexpand test.tex > test_out.tex` from the command line.

The table remains in the middle of the document, even though compiling as pdf puts the table at the end.

Comment: There is the endfloat package.  It copies specific environments (figure, table) to a file then inputs the file at the end, or after \processdelayedfloats.

Comment: I have probably obscured my question a bit by trying to simplify.  I want to move actual code within the file in some way, not just the position of the tables.  If it helps to clarify, I am in the unfortunate situation of trying to produce a word document for a journal that requires it, from a complex latex document that has tables added via \input.  So I first 'flatten' the file using latexpand.  I am already using endfloat as suggested by John, but this does not fully solve the problem.  However John's comment points to a partial solution: add \include{test.ttt} at the desired location